# C Pointer error : cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in initialization

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I'm doing following code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
   {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int *p =a;

    }
```

But my console shows this error.

```
cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in initialization
```

I don't know why. Can anyone tell me reason & solution?

Here is the screenshot included.[https://imgur.com/a/U94vtKG]

Comment: Try `p = &a[0];`.  Is it really the true code that is posted?

Comment: Ok the program is running. But the problem (cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in initialization) still showing in problem tab. Check the imgur image.

Comment: Yes , it's the true one . I'm pretty much new into pointers so IDK what's the problem. The program is running but still showing the problem.

Comment: In the imgur image the code file is marked as modified, i.e. you did not save the file content. Are you sure you compile what you see?

Comment: The code got compiled, but it was still showing the problem. IDK bug maybe.

Comment: And the "modified" indication was not present any more? You may need to save your code manually before compiling.

Comment: You should also look at the command window where the compilation is done. Normally the error message also contains the erronous code line and may contain a bit more than what is shown by VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in initialization

means that actually instead of this correct declaration

```
int *p = a;
```

you wrote

```
int *p = &a;
```

Or if in realty the array `a` is declared like a two-dimensional array

```
int a[][10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

then you need to write

```
int ( *p )[10] = a;
```

That is your presented code in the question does not corresponds to the error message.

Usually such an error occurs when a function declared for example as

```
void f( int *a );
```

is called like

```
f( &a );
```

instead of calling it like

```
f( a );
```

where `a` is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: @Zeph_The_Hungry_Loli Array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to a pointer to its first element. So if you have one dimensional array of integers then it is converted to the pointer of the type int *, If you have a two-dimensional array like int a[][10] then its element has the type int[10] and a pointer to this element will look like int ( *p )[10]. It seems you made a typo somewhere. For example you could call a function like f( &a ); while the function parameter has the type int *

Comment: So array designators are  basically pointers in a nutshell which points to the first element of array? Let's say a[]={1,3,4,5}. So if I print only a (not a[0] ) will I get an address value or the first element? Or whatever I'm saying is entirely wrong? Sorry if I sound stupid, but I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: @Zeph_The_Hungry_Loli You are right. In fact  array designator implicitly converted to a pointer yields an expression equivalent to the expression &a[0].

Answer (score 1):

`a` is 10 `int` pointers. You cannot assign one `int` pointer to 10 `int` pointers.

If you want `p` to point to the first element of `a`, change:

```c
int *p = a;
```

to:

```c
int *p = &a[0]
```

Comment: Ok the program is running. But the problem (cannot convert 'int ()[10]' to 'int' in initialization) still showing in problem tab. Check the imgur image.